# estimating probabilty

Tags: probability

I would like some help with a probability problem. Given that $23.5$% are obese, $22.7$% of Americans are smokers, and $4.7$% are both obese and smokers.

Estimate the probablity of
1) A person that is neither obese or a smoker
2) not obese but does smoke
3) obese but doesn't smoke

For 1) I think it simply $100-4.7 = 95.3$%

2) ?

3) ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.
This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the event that someone is a smoker, $B$ that they are obese, and $\bar A,\bar B$ that they are not those things.

1. This is poorly phrased. To me it sounds like (grammatically) it should be that a person is "neither obese nor a smoker", which means some one is not obese *and* not a smoker. This is
   $$P(\bar A \cap \bar B) = 1- P(A\cup B) = 1-[P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)]$$
   where in the first step I use De Morgan's law and in the second step I use the inclusion-exclusion rule.
2. The event is that someone is not obese and a smoker. Then 
   $$P(\bar B \cap A).$$
   Use a Venn diagram to see the result.

I leave 3. for you.